# Algorithm used for symmetric key encryption by quorum

Tags: quorum, encryption

What are the symmetric key encryption techniques used by the enclave in quorum to encrypt the payload? The documentation of quorum mentions that the enclave uses a symmetric key to encrypt the payload but there is no mention of the algorithm that is used. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is documented in several places and in the source code directly. Here is a link to an expanded explanation of what happens in the Tessera enclave: http://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Security/Framework/Quorum%20Network%20Security/Nodes/Permissioning/Network%20Permissioning/#enclave-encryption-technique. Tessera and c11n use NaCl and Argon2.